# Android: singleton with shutdown hook

Tags: java, android, service, hook

Android provides a service infrastructure, but it's a bit verbose for my current simple needs. I'm using a singleton to provide a service, which has some internal state.

I'm persisting the internal state in a `SharedPreferences` bundle. To get an instance of the singleton, a `Context` is required, which is used the first time the singleton is needed to create it reading the prefs:

```
MyService mS = MyServiceImpl.getInstance((Context) this);
```

From that point onward, the `Context` passed is ignored and the preferences are read from memory.

Now, I'd like to persist the internal state back to the bundle upon exit. Shutdown hooks are not supported, however, and I really don't want to keep track of what Activity is using the service.

Is there a simple solution for this, something akin to the shutdown hook, or do I have to use a bound `Service` and bind it/unbind it in each `Activity`?

Comment: Why not simply persist your changes when you make them?

Comment: I'll probably end up doing that, but was curious